# How to draw a round corner window a border?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

in win32, we can use SetWindowRgn to give the window a round corner, how to draw a border for this rigon? it's not a rect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the [`WM_NCPAINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145212%28VS.85%29.aspx) message and you can draw the window frame and borders by yourself.

Comment: @lovespring: I never mentioned a rectangle. You can draw anything you want. Maybe you're looking for the [`RoundRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162944%28VS.85%29.aspx) function?

Comment: just use fillRgn! I don't know this API before.